# Access function from require()'d file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

Following is a code sample:

test.js:

```
function print(t){
    console.log(t);
}
```

index.js:

```
var test = require('./test.js');
test.print("ok");
```

I get a `test.show is not a function` error, and I'm not sure why it won't work if with other npm modules seem to work. I am using browserify to make the require work in the browser.

How does requiring files that are not from a module work in npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to export it first:

`test.js:`

```
function print(t){
    console.log(t);
}

exports.print = print;
```

Then you can call it:

```
Victors-MacBook-Pro:a kohl$ node
> var test = require('./test')
undefined
> test.print("ok");
ok
```